# If live & neutral alternates, why is neutral always $0V$?

Tags: electric-circuits

So I've been confused on why the neutral is always at $0V$, I know that because it is earthed, but the concept that I know about AC Current that the Voltage keeps alternating ex(from $+240$ to $-240$).

I just don't get on why it is always $0V$. I'm not a pro yet at this section, so please answer it assuming I'm still student.*and please don't mark this as duplicate because the answers out there are still not clear for me. Thankyou!

Please refer to this diagram for simplicity.

[image]

Comment: "0V" means it is on the same potential as the earth, your diagram shows that the "neutral" wire is grounded, hence it is the same potential as that of the earth almost everywhere.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm confused on how voltage alternates if the neutral wire is always 0, supposedly in an ac circuit it keeps changing from 0-120v and vice versa...

Comment: You may call *any* point in the circuit as being 0V. In theoretical electrostatics the 0V point is usually defined at infinity; in everyday practice we reference *arbitrarily* the earth as being at 0V. What matters for physics/engineering/life is the *voltage drop between two points*. Remember, the current over a resistor $R$ is $I=V_x/R$ where $V_x$ is the voltage between the two terminals of the resistor not "the voltage" at any of its terminals.

Comment: Kevin, I've flagged this question for moderator attention because of its similarity to the closed and now deleted question [AC in Neutral & Live](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/435097/9887).  Are you the same person as [PC Mining](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/209491/pc-mining) using two different accounts to ask again a question that has been closed?

Comment: Who's Pc Mining? I've just read the answers in that forum but they all don't make sense for me...

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a type of potential - electric potential. This means voltage is meaningless unless it is expressed with respect to a reference point. This reference point is the neutral line, defined to be at $0V$. The hot line then alternates between $\text{neutral voltage}\pm 240$ (technically more since the maximum voltage for $240V_{rms}$ is greater than $240V$). Technically speaking, if the mains supply caused the voltage at the neutral line to vary with respect to the earth, so long as the voltage at the hot line stayed at $\text{neutral voltage}\pm 240$ it would still be a working $240V$ supply (however, this would be quite dangerous and cause a whole host of other problems).

Comment: What could be the problems?

Comment: I'm just confused why only the live side is alternating(240v), while the neutral stays the same, and what's the difference with a usual ac circuit?